# call a SQL Server Stored Procedure with Parameter in R

Tags: sql, sql-server, r

Can anyone give code to call a SQL server Stored Procedure with Parameter in R?

This is all I have and it is not working:

```
dbhandle <- odbcDriverConnect('driver={SQL Server};server=SWD-CHISSIS01;database=GlobalRiskManagement;trusted_connection=true')
data <-sqlQuery(dbhandle, "EXEC my_Stored_Proc  @jyear=2013, @ddate=9/25/2013")
odbcCloseAll()
```

Thank you.

Comment: In my experience, ODBC connections != ability to execute any db command just as if I'm logged into the db manually. Depends on the driver, probably. But I don't think you can do anything but your basic select/update/delete etc.

Comment: Ok. Is there any OTHER way to call a SQL SERVER stored PROC in R with paramers? Thank you!

Comment: Not that I know of, no. If you can do it from somewhere else (say, a bash script) you could call the bash script from R via `system`. But I just think that ODBC connections do not support this, and that's the only option I know of for connecting to sql server from R.

Comment: ODBC connection support this in VBA and C#. But you are saying there is nothing in R?

Comment: I should have hedged more, in that I think it's driver implementation specific. I've never heard of anyone being able to do anything more than select/update/etc from an ODBC connection in R. I don't doubt that it's possible in other implementations of the driver.

Comment: You say it isnt working, what happens? Is there an error, and if so what is it? My expectation is that it should work in some shape or form as per your comment re VBA & C#. It may however need the statement formated a little differently like EXEC ('my_Stored_Proc  @... ');

Comment: I have found this: http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/DBI/DBI.pdf which has a "dbCallProc" but I see no implementation for the SQL Server driver.  Any ideas on this? TY

Comment: As it says in the docs you linked to, that isn't implemented yet. So I think that supports my original guess that this isnt possible at the moment.

Answer (score 3):

Just to clarify, the in the code above, the **'s should not be included in the code so it should say:
data <-sqlQuery(dbhandle, "set nocount on\nEXEC my_Stored_Proc  @jyear=2013, @ddate=9/25/2013")

This works for me.  Thanks to all who replied.

Answer (score 2):

```
dbhandle <- odbcDriverConnect('driver={SQL Server};server=SWD-CHISSIS01;database=GlobalRiskManagement;trusted_connection=true')
data <-sqlQuery(dbhandle, "**set nocount on\n**EXEC my_Stored_Proc  @jyear=2013, @ddate=9/25/2013")
odbcCloseAll()
```

Comment: This is your answer or what?

Comment: While this may answer the question it’s always a good idea to put some text in your answer to explain what you're doing. Read [how to write a good answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: The SET NOCOUNT ON is the key to the solution.   While I haven't figured out how to parameterize the query yet (just use sql injection techniques) -- I was unable to get any data back until adding SET NOCOUNT to my command.   I understand why but not sure this is the place to discuss it.  Basically the RODBC library is taking the first response from SQL Server (which are the row counts from each sub command).

Answer (score 0):

Here is the answer:

```
library(RODBC)

GetData <- function (Field1) {
  conn<- odbcDriverConnect('driver={SQL Server};server=SERVER;database=DATABASE;trusted_connection=yes')

  data <- sqlQuery(conn,paste("exec my_STOREDPROC @Field1= '", Field1 , "';",sep =""),errors=FALSE)
  odbcCloseAll()
  data
)
}
```

Comment: Could you elaborate on your answer a little? What is Field1 for example?

Answer (score 0):

I used the solution with the "SET NOCOUNT ON" version. But the stored procedure was executed and stopped abruptly. So I decided to use the command shell using the "sqlcmd" command. Here I made a function:

```
callStoredProc = function(server,BD,storedProc,sParams){
    sFileName = paste("log_",gsub(":", "_", gsub("-", "_", gsub("\\.", "_", Sys.time()))),storedProc,".txt",sep="")
    sQuery = paste("sqlcmd -E -S ",server," -d ",BD," -Q \"EXECUTE ",storedProc," ",sParams,"\" -o \"",sFileName,"\"", sep="")
    shell(sQuery)
}#callStoredProc
```

Answer (score 0):

I am using RSQLS library to connect to SQL Server.
I use "con" as my connection variable, "param" as all of my parameters, in this case they are dates. The problem to get around is that paste() does not preserve embedded single quotes separately so you have to build up the procedure call.

```
fromdate<-"2020-06-01"
thrudate<-"2021-05-31"

# param is not special, just a variable name
param<-paste( "'", fromdate, "', '",thrudate,"' ",  sep="")

# call the procedure
df <- pull_data(con,  paste(" EXEC myProcedure", param), showprogress = TRUE)

# this gets passed to pull_data(): 
#        " EXEC myProcedure '2020-06-01', '2021-05-31' "
```